# Angular: Map function stop looping after a condition is met

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have my angular code as below. I am looping in to my array to find certain element and map the data. After I find my element, I want to stop looping as the element is unique and I don't want further checking

```
this.staffData.map(staff => {
  if(staff.id === staffId){
    staff.name === newStaffName;
    staff.dept = newDept;
    staff.address = newAddress//After this I want to break 
}})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: You don't want to use `map`. `map` is a set operation, it doesn't iterate in a predictable manner. Use a `for each` loop and break on your desired condition.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `find` instead:

```
const newStaffName = this.staffData.find(staff => staff.id === staffId).name;
```

Comment: I am not trying to find the name for that staffid. I am trying to update the name with the newStaffName

Comment: Then change the trailing `).name;` for `).name = newStaffName;`. And don't assign it to a `const`. `find()` returns an element from the array that matches a condition, then you do with that element what you will.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the question clearly. I am actually trying to update few parameters not just the name. That is the reason I have used map. Is there a way to update other parameters also with find?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward, annotated alternative with [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
staff = [{
    name: "Mark",
    dept: "Sales",
    address: "123 Fake St"
  },
  {
    name: "Jim",
    dept: "Sales",
    address: "123 Real St"
  },
  {
    name: "Fred",
    dept: "Sales",
    address: "123 Imaginary Ln"
  }
];

console.dir(staff);

// Find the index of the person based on whatever criteria you want
index = staff.findIndex(person => person.name === "Jim");

// Update that index with a new object
staff[index] = {
  // Retain values you don't want to change
  name: staff[index].name,
  address: staff[index].address,
  
  // Change those you do
  dept: "Development"
}

console.dir(staff);
```